# Suggest range input (numerical/currency) for dollar amount

Tags: input-fields, range, currency

I have a new-to-me UX challenge that we're working through that involves a user giving us either a single fixed dollar amount, OR choosing to give us a soft minimum/maximum range. The dollar amounts in this field will typically be in the tens of millions of dollars, so that's 8 digits, and it is a different experience than putting in single integer ranges like "1-5".

Let me know your thoughts on making this the simplest experience for our users!

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Tim. Can you clarify the problem you're facing? What possible solutions have you tried? What didn't work about them?

Comment: Give example for the soft minimum/maximum range.

Comment: How precise do the ranges need to be? I.e. can it be as general as "_10-13 million_" or (in the extreme) as precise as "_10,575,222 to 12,888,412_"? This probably affects the choice of "best" control.

Comment: Also, do you need this also on a mobile platform?

Answer (score -1):

I would use a **Range Slider**, the range slider can have added functionality to suit particular needs like min max ranges, draggable range, editable min-max,etc.

The display of units doesn't need to be anything special but a numerical format:

[image: Range Slider]

You can find them here:

https://jqueryui.com/slider/#range, or do a search in codepen for more.

Comment: I wouldn't use it on mobile, though. I always struggle with these controls if I need to select a small range since I have large fingers - I guess I am not alone in this....

Comment: Not to mention if you're going for something more precise than rough numbers ("1,325,235" instead of "1 million") your users will hate you.

Comment: @MariuszCiesla: The poster left it unclear on what kind of precision is needed along with mobile support, but a range plus a precision input could work, for mobile I would probably use native controls.